# Insert if Number not Exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to insert all the numbers from tbl2 table into tbl1 table. But if tbl2.number already exist in tbl1.number then dont insert it. How to do this?

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (number) SELECT tbl2.number FROM tbl2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it makes sense to have a unique (or primary) index for `tbl1.number`, then you can use `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl1 (number) SELECT tbl2.number FROM tbl2
```

Comment: Is this faster than resokk answer?

Comment: @user791022 - I suspect that the answer depends on the relative sizes of the tables and on the amount of overlap. The only way to know, I think, is to benchmark. The `SET profiling=1`, `SHOW PROFILES`, and `SHOW PROFILE` statements are useful for this. On first impression, it looks like Roman's solution does twice as much index checking, but MySQL might optimize a lot of this away.

Answer (score 2):

Plain SQL (non specific for MySQL):

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (number) SELECT tbl2.number FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.number not in (SELECT number from tbl1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use an "IIF" function with "IsNull" to determine whether or not the tbl2 number exists in the input field.